# OnScrollChanged event for my ScrollViewer in MVVM WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, scrollviewer

I wish to use an attached property to handle the ScrollChanged event of my ScrollViewer. At the minute the event and logic are handled in the UI code behind, which obviously goes against MVVM somewhat. I was wondering if anyone has any ideas about how you do this with attached properties? The only resources I've found seem very long winded. Here is the code I have at the minute:

XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScroller" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollChanged="MyScroller_OnScrollChanged">
```

UI Codebehind:

```
private void MyScroller_OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e) {
            var scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;


            if ((Math.Abs(e.ExtentHeightChange) < 0) && (Math.Abs(e.ExtentWidthChange) < 0)) return;
            var xMousePositionOnScrollViewer = Mouse.GetPosition(scrollViewer).X;
            var yMousePositionOnScrollViewer = Mouse.GetPosition(scrollViewer).Y;
            var offsetX = e.HorizontalOffset + xMousePositionOnScrollViewer;
            var offsetY = e.VerticalOffset + yMousePositionOnScrollViewer;

            var oldExtentWidth = e.ExtentWidth - e.ExtentWidthChange;
            var oldExtentHeight = e.ExtentHeight - e.ExtentHeightChange;

            var relx = offsetX / oldExtentWidth;
            var rely = offsetY / oldExtentHeight;

            offsetX = Math.Max(relx * e.ExtentWidth - xMousePositionOnScrollViewer, 0);
            offsetY = Math.Max(rely * e.ExtentHeight - yMousePositionOnScrollViewer, 0);



            scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(offsetX);
            scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(offsetY);
        }
```

Comment: Saying that "*the event and logic are handled in the UI code behind ... obviously goes against MVVM*" is a misconception. MVVM doesn't mean that you can't have code behind in your UI.

Comment: @Clemens So you think this code belongs in the UI code behind rather than being handled in an attached property class? Genuinely asking as I assumed if you could it's better to keep any code out of the UI code behind.

Comment: You haven't explained what exactly the code is supposed to do, but to me it seems to be purely view related. No need to have it in your view model.

Comment: @Clemens I have zoom functionality in my view model using a Scale Transform - this is simply to offset the scroll wheel so I don't scroll up at the same time as zooming in.

Comment: That code is very view specific. That sort of thing would be done either as code on some sort of usercontrol / custom control or as a behavior. Either way you can manually test once then re-use many times. If it's specific to one view then there's no value in moving it.

Comment: @danny10846 I would put a ScaleTransform in the view. I might, in some cases, store the scale factor in the viewmodel as a Zoom property. Anyway. Nobody's answering the question, so I will: An attached property would simply attach that same event handler to the target's ScrollChanged event. Very simple.

Comment: @danny10846 [This answer handles a TextChanged event via a behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31953755/424129) -- ignore everything but just how it handles that one event, there's a lot of stuff there that doesn't apply to your question. Your PropertyChanged handler will be just one line: `(d as ScrollViewer).ScrollChanged += MyStaticScrolllChangedHandler`;

Comment: @EdPlunkett Hi Ed, I read through your link and seem to have sorted my issue. I created an attached property class where I defined my logic for offsetting the scroll and then simply added: 

`<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
               <attachedProperties:ScrollBehaviour>

               </attachedProperties:ScrollBehaviour>
   </i:Interaction.Behaviors>`

to my XAML. Thanks for your help!